# How to remove width and height from img tag, inside a MySQL column?

Tags: mysql, regex

I found how to search it using

```
SELECT *
FROM `catalog_product_entity_text`
WHERE `value` REGEXP 'width=\"(.*)\"'
```

But I cant find how to search only for img tag (and not width on divs for exmaple), and then to replace with nothing, to remove it.

Comment: Please show sample data and what you want to accomplish.  How do you represent "img tag" versus "div" for instance?

Comment: It might be better to deal with this in your application business logic, where you can use a proper HTML manipulation library. For example if you are using PHP, DOMDocument would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged it as [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)

You can use this regex:

```
<img.+?width="(.+?)">
```

Use it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `catalog_product_entity_text`
WHERE `value` REGEXP '<img.+?width=\"(.+?)\">'
```

However, I would suggest you not to parse HTML by regex.

Comment: But how to replace it by ""?, I need to remove the width and height from my IMG. Anything better than regex?